# Stop UISearchDisplayController from resigning first responder on searchbutton click

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've got a `UISearchDisplayController` and I want to avoid closing keyboard after search when clicking on the keyboard's search button. 
I tried to use the solution of Josh Cashwell from another Post: setting `UISearchBarDelegate` and implementing `SearchBarShouldEndEditing`. But I've got a problem to catch the right event:
`SearchBarShouldEndEditing` shall return yes in any case (i.e. clicking anywhere else in view, dragging resulttableview,...) except when clicking search button.

My Implementation:
I tried to set a variable in `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` and use it in `searchBarShouldEndEditing` to determine whether I shall return `YES` or `NO`. Works fine while iteratively tipping Searchtext and pressing search, but when clicking anywhere else in the view after pressing search, the keyboard does not close.

So hopefully there is a better way to check whether `searchBarShouldEndEditing` is called because of clicking the search button, but I don't get it.

Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want the keyboard to not go away when the user clicks the "Search" button in the keyboard?

But anyways... the way I would solve the problem is that in your `searchBarShouldEndEditing:` delegate method (before it returns `YES`), make the text field that you want the keyboard to stay up for the new first responder (via UIResponder's [`becomeFirstResponder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/becomeFirstResponder) method).  That way the keyboard wouldn't have a reason to dismiss.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks a lot for your response. The Problem is: becomeFirstResponder does not work with UISearchDisplayController. And I don't want to set focus everytime.

Comment: I wasn't telling you to call `becomeFirstResponder` on your `UISearchDisplayController` but on whatever ***other*** text field (not part of your `UISearchDisplayController`) that you want your keyboard to stay up for.

Comment: The Problem is: becomeFirstResponder does not work with UISearchDisplayController (I tried to call it in searchBarSearchButtonClicked - it does not work). I don't want to set focus everytime in searchBarShouldEndEditing. Here's the background: It shall be possible to use a scanner to enter text in the searchbar. The scanner sends enter after scan. After scanning focus shall stay at the searchbar so you don't have to click into the searchbar to restart scanning. But when the user manually tabs outside, focus shall get lost.

Comment: Without SearchDisplayController, just using searchBar, you manually have to call resignfirstresponder, but with SearchDisplayController focus automatically gets lost when pressing search. - That's my experience.

Comment: well... I'm now thoroughly confused as to what you're trying to do.  Maybe somebody else looking at this question will have a better grasp and a better answer for you.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks a lot. Sorry for being so confusing. We implemented an article search. You can enter a part of articletext into searchbar, but you also should be able to scan barcodes. When there is only 1 article found, the article is automatically added to the order, so you can restart scanning. Everything works fine except focusing searchbar.

Comment: What about implementing the `UISearchBarDelegate` method `-searchBarShouldEndEditing:` and conditionally returning `NO`? I think that should keep the search bar from resigning first responder status.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your response. Problem: then focus stays at searchbar permanently. I can't edit any other Textfield.

Comment: Solved: Used an NSTimeInterval to save Time of pressing Searchbutton. On SearchBarShouldEndEdiing timedifference from now to the saved value is checked. If (diff < 0.001) {return NO;} else  {return YES;} I don't know whether this is a nice solution but it works. Thanks a lot Michael and Mark!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Used an NSTimeInterval to save Time of pressing Searchbutton. On SearchBarShouldEndEdiing timedifference from now to the saved value is checked. If (diff < 0.001) {return NO;} else {return YES;} I don't know whether this is a smart solution but it works.